# Get the previous and next values of a string

Tags: java, string

I am using a NoSQL database which doesn't allow equality conditions of attributes that are projected. Eg Unequality operations such as `select a from table where a > 10` and is allowed `select a from table where b < 10`, but `select a from table where a = 10` is not allowed. Of course I need to use an equality in my case, so I want to turn a equality operations into an inequality operation.

So I need to retrieve a record by email. If could I would go `select email from table where email = 'myemail@email.com'`, but this is not allowed so I want to get the lexicographic value right before `myemail@email.com` and the value right after.  So the query would look like this:

```
select email from table where email < [1 value above] and email > [1 value below]
```

This way the statement would still return `myemail@email.com`. I am having trouble though how to accomplish this.

Usually to compare strings I go `"myemail@email.com".compare("myemail@email.ca")` to see which one bigger and which one is smaller. This method compares the values somehow based on lexicographic, but how? My question is how to get the lexicographic value right below a string and the lexicographic value right after the string?

Comment: What kind of weird NoSQL supports `<` and `>` but not `=`?

Comment: @Andreas Google Datastore - If using projection queries you cannot project an attribute you are using in a equality filter condition. https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/projectionqueries

Comment: Does this mystery flavor of NoSQL support the `NOT` operator? Why not just do `select * from T where not (email < :val or email > :val)`?

Comment: @nbrooks Unfortunaley it does NOT (pun intended).

Comment: Why would you even want to do `select a from table where a = 10`. If you know `a` is `10`, why return it? It's meaningless/redundant/superfluous. Now `select b from table where a = 10` makes sense, and *that* is allowed.

Comment: Because I need to update the entity. In Google Datastore an update is really an insert. It deletes/overwrites the entire entity, so I must have all the values to be able to reconstruct it.

Comment: So read all the other values, except the one you already know. Or **don't use projection**, which only returns a subset of the values anyway. Return the whole entity. I mean, you're going to need the whole entity for the update, right? As you said: *I must have all the values*

Comment: @Andreas well if I was smart I would just do that then haha. I never thought I would already know this value in my code and I could use that. Thanks, now I feel pretty dumb.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The string immediately after a string is easy. It's just

```
str + '\0'
```

This works because `'\0'` is the lowest possible `char` value.

The string immediately *before* `str` is more tricky. If the string ends in `'\0'` you can just remove it. If the string doesn't end in `'\0'` you have serious issues. As an example, let's consider the string `"foo"`.

Each of the following strings is below `"foo"` and each one is bigger than the last.

```
"fon" + Character.MAX_VALUE;
"fon" + Character.MAX_VALUE + Character.MAX_VALUE;
"fon" + Character.MAX_VALUE + Character.MAX_VALUE + Character.MAX_VALUE;
...
```

The largest `String` value less than `"foo"` is `"fon"` followed by something like `2^31 - 4` copies of `Character.MAX_VALUE` (this may not be right. I'm not sure what the largest possible length of a `char[]` is). However, you will not be able to store such a string in memory.

You should therefore try to find an different solution to your problem.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your alphabet is `a-z0-9`, and case-insensitive, you can treat your string as a base-36 number and simply increment/decrement the values using simple arithmetic.

Java's [`Long.valueOf`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Long.html#valueOf(java.lang.String,%20int)) method allows you to take a String with a given radix, and convert it to it's (base 10) `Long` equivalent. Once you have a `Long` instance, you can simply add 1 to get the next value.

```
public static String nextString(String str) {
    return Long.toString(Long.valueOf(norm(str), 36) + 1, 36);
}
```

To reverse the operation, you can use the [`Long.toString`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Long.html#toString(long,%20int)) method, which takes a `long` instance and converts it to a `String` representation, with a specified radix. So you can represent your base-10 `long` as a base-36 number, which will include the letters `a-z`.

```
public static String prevString(String str) {
    return Long.toString(Long.valueOf(norm(str), 36) - 1, 36);
}
```

You'll want to normalize your strings when using these methods, so this will filter our invalid characters, ensure that everything is lower-case, and prevent null pointer exceptions or number format exceptions.

```
private static String norm(String str) {
    if (str == null) {
        return "0";
    }
    return str.toLowerCase().replaceAll("[^a-z0-9]", "");
}
```